# Get values from xml in Android Java

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created a new xml file with the name "constant.xml" in the folder values.

How can I access the values?

The file is construced like the strings xml. For this I need only

```
 getString(R.string.STRING_NAME).
```

But R.constant.STRING_NAME is not avaiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may access string resources the same way as you would if they were located in the `strings.xml` file; location does not affect your ability to call them. In your case, you can access your string resource by simply using `getString(R.string.STRING_NAME)`, as you would with a standard string located in the `strings.xml` file.